# How to disable field validation on finder page in Spring Roo

Tags: spring, dojo, spring-roo

So I have created a custom search page that allows for me to search Customers by any field, and all the fields are optional. To do this, I had to create a custom `<form:find>` tag and comment out this line:

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));</script> -->
```

This allows me to submit the form. But here is the problem: if I click inside a field and click outside of it, without entering any text, the "This field is required" validation error pops up.

I can still submit the form, and the search page works, but I would like to fix this annoying, incorrect error.

Here is the .jspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:find_without_validation finderName="ByOutputFormatAndStorageDeviceAndWorkOrderAndServiceOffering" id="ff_com_eg_egmedia_bizapp_model_ServiceItem" path="/serviceitems" z="b0NZUow+hQ11Ruy9n/4oyBOWOBs=">
        <field:select_optional disableFormBinding="true" field="outputFormat" id="f_com_eg_egmedia_bizapp_model_ServiceItem_outputFormat" items="${outputformatenums}" path="/outputformatenums" required="false" z="user-managed"/>
        <field:select_optional disableFormBinding="true" field="storageDevice" id="f_com_eg_egmedia_bizapp_model_ServiceItem_storageDevice" items="${storagedeviceenums}" path="/storagedeviceenums" required="false" z="user-managed"/>
        <field:select_optional disableFormBinding="true" field="workOrder" id="f_com_eg_egmedia_bizapp_model_ServiceItem_workOrder" itemValue="id" items="${workorders}" path="/workorders" required="false" z="user-managed"/>
        <field:select_optional disableFormBinding="true" field="serviceOffering" id="f_com_eg_egmedia_bizapp_model_ServiceItem_serviceOffering" itemValue="id" items="${serviceofferings}" path="/serviceofferings" required="false" z="user-managed"/>
    </form:find_without_validation>
</div>
```

My `<field:select_optional>` tag is just the default `<field:select>` tag with an extra `<option value="" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `select.tagx` in your project and inside this file find the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_${sec_field}_id', widgetType: 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect', widgetAttrs : {hasDownArrow : true}})); </script>
```

Inside decorators `widgetAttrs` add a new option:

```
required: ${required}
```

So that the edited line looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_${sec_field}_id', widgetType: 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect', widgetAttrs : {hasDownArrow : true, required: ${required}}})); </script>
```

After this modification the `required` attribute in `field:select` tag will work well.

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering why the 'required' attribute doesn't work without our modifications.

Comment: I've found several bugs like this one and I assume that Spring-Roo is not very successful project. Spring did abandon Roo - now it is open source